# TypeError in match

Tags: python-3.x

i try to run this match function but it doesn't work what i wrong?

```
def process_data(data):
    type_data = type(data)
    match data in type_data:
        case 'str':
            print("Data is a string")
        case 'int':
            print("Data is an integer")
        case 'float':
            print("Data is a float")
        case 'list':
            print("Data is a list")
        case 'dict':
            print("Data is a dictionary")
        case 'set':
            print("Data is a set")
        case 'tuple':
            print("Data is a tuple")
        case _:
            print("Invalid data type")

process_data("hello")
process_data(42)
```

i try to run example function to check type of given args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the code this is the syntax

```
def process_data(data):
         match date:
             case bool():
                 print('Data is a bool')
             case str():
                 print("Data is a string")
             case int():
                 print("Data is an integer")
             case float():
                 print("Data is a float")
             case list():
                 print("Data is a list")
             case dict():
                 print("Data is a dictionary")
             case set():
                 print("Data is a set")
             case tuple():
                 print("Data is a tuple")
             case _:
                 print("Invalid data type")
    
    
    process_data(True)
    process_data("hello") # Output: Data is a string
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the Strings from cases as you are matching only strings.

It should look like:

```
def process_data(data):
    type_data = type(data)
    match type_data:
        case str:
            print("Data is a string")
        case int:
            print("Data is an integer")
        case float:
            print("Data is a float")
        case list:
            print("Data is a list")
        case dict:
            print("Data is a dictionary")
        case set:
            print("Data is a set")
        case tuple:
            print("Data is a tuple")
        case _:
            print("Invalid data type")

process_data("hello")
process_data(42)
```

The output should be like this :

```
Data is a string
Data is an integer
```